# UPDATE VIA CSV LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3

Tenho esse parâmetro para importar dados vias CSV e quero saber como que faço agora para criar a função de UPDATE baseada no campo CÓDIGO.

```
public function importEstoque(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $csvData = file_get_contents($file);
    $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $row = array_combine($header, $row);
        Estoque::insert([
            'codigo' => $row['Código'],
            'nome' => $row['Produto'],
            'estoque' => $row['Qtd.'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta teria como explicar melhor ?

Comment: Se for o que estou pensando, você quer fazer um outro método para atualizar, e fazer a atualização com base no código ?

Comment: No casa não seria pelo ID e sim pelo campo CÓDIGO que nesta aplicação represente o código de barras do produto.

Então o usuário vai importar um arquivo com o CÓDIGO de barras, Produto e Quantidade, com isso, faz o update na base.

É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Nessa mesma função importEstoque ?

Comment: Pode ser uma nova função, coloquei ela como exemplo.

Comment: Da pra fazer uma que atualize e insira ao mesmo tempo, mas vou criar uma só pra atualizar com base nesse import que você fez

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado pelo apoio \o/

Comment: Testa ai e me fala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz o método par que ele atualize o nome do produto e o estoque, com base no código já cadastrado no sistema.

```
public function importUpdateEstoque(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'file' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $csvData = file_get_contents($file);
    $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));
    $header = array_shift($rows);
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $row = array_combine($header, $row);
        Estoque::where('codigo', $row['Código'])
            ->update([
                'nome' => $row['Produto'],
                'estoque' => $row['Qtd.'],
            ]);
    }
}
```

Caso seja necessário colocar mais condições é só adicionar outros `where();` e caso queria atualizar mais colunas e só adiciona dentro do array dentro de `update();`.

Comment: Deu certo \o/
Muito obrigado pelo apoio!!!!